# Filling the gap of the lemma about bilinear map $\text{Lin}^2(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathbf{R})$ and endomorphism space End$(\mathbf{R}^n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

In Kolk's [Multidimensional Real Analysis I: Differentiation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521551145)

He proved the following lemma 2.9.1 to help find the Hessian matrix:

[image]

The proof he gave is simple:

[image]

The following are Lemma 2.7.4 and 2.6.1:

[image]
[image]

However, I found there are big gaps in the proof.

For $T \in \text{Lin}^2(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R})$, from Lemma 2.7.4, there is a linear isomorphism $v$, such that $T(h,k) = (v(T)h)k, v(T)\in \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathbf{R}))$.

Then from Lemma 2.6.1, we can find another  linear isomorphism $\mu$, such that $T(h,k) = (v(T)h)k = \langle \mu(v(T)h), k \rangle$. Note that $v(T)h \in \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathbf{R})$, so we can apply lemma 2.6.1.
How does $\langle \mu(v(T)h), k \rangle$ become $\langle \lambda(T)h, k \rangle$ where $\lambda$ is again a linear isomorphism?

**Update 1:**
In fact, there is an intrinsic relationship between a general bilinear form and a linear operator, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3052663/549321):
But I still don't know how to get some insight from it.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the composition of $\mu$ and $v$, by definition.

Comment: @Thorgott I think it's not. Since, $\mu$ takes $(v(T)h)$ as input, rather than $v(T)$

Comment: Sorry, I was writing sloppily. For each $T$, $\lambda(T)$ is the composition $\mu\circ v(T)$.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your commet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thorgott pointed out in the comment. I am almost there.
We have:
$ v(T)\in \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathbf{R}))$. We also have $\mu \in \text{Lin}(\text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n, \mathbf{R}),\mathbf{R}^n)$. So **by defintion of function composition** , $\mu \circ v(T) \in \text{Lin}(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R}^n) = \text{End}(\mathbf{R}^n)$. Here, $\mu \circ v(T)$ is $ \lambda(T)$. $\mu$ and $v$ is linear isomorphism, so is $\lambda$.